# ValueError: min_faces_per_person=70 is too restrictive

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, python-3.6, face-recognition

I'm practicing **Faces recognition example using eigenfaces and SVMs** which is on the official scikit-learn website.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-face-recognition-py

But when I run here：

```
from __future__ import print_function

from time import time
import logging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC


print(__doc__)

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')


# #############################################################################
# Download the data, if not already on disk and load it as numpy arrays

lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)
```

But I am getting an error that tells me：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\神经网络与深度学习\麦子学院-深度学习\(Part One)深度学习基础\代码与素材
\代码与素材(1)\03SVM\plot_face_recognition.py", line 54, in <module>
    lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py", line 335, in fetch_lfw_people
    min_faces_per_person=min_faces_per_person, color=color, slice_=slice_)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 562, in __call__
    return self._cached_call(args, kwargs)[0]
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 510, in _cached_call
    out, metadata = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 744, in call
    output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py", line 231, in _fetch_lfw_people
    min_faces_per_person)
ValueError: min_faces_per_person=70 is too restrictive
```

I don't understand why?My python version is 3.6.2, scikit-learn version is v0.19.0

Comment: Reading [the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c1eee276fa501965e7b4e23e6349031092e33131/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py#L208) it seems there is some trouble with path-stuff which effects in an empy fileset.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14 and python 2 and not getting any error. Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6484) is of relevance. You can post a new issue there.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is a red herring:

```
ValueError: min_faces_per_person=70 is too restrictive
```

Your stack trace shows this error comes from ...sklearn\datasets\lfw.py", line 231, in _fetch_lfw_people

Looking at the code in _fetch_lfw_people, it shows when this error is generated

```
n_faces = len(file_paths)
if n_faces == 0:
    raise ValueError("min_faces_per_person=%d is too restrictive" %
                     min_faces_per_person)
```

This happens if it does not find any (image) files to process.

I got this error when I was behind an internet proxy, and this Python code wouldn't download the file for me.

To solve this, I downloaded these 5 files manually and placed it in the ~/scikit_learn_data/lfw_home folder. You can find these URLs by looking for RemoteFileMetadata( in lfw.py.

```
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976018 #lfw.tgz
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976015 #lfw-funneled.tgz
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976012 #pairsDevTrain.txt
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976009 #pairsDevTest.txt
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976006 #pairs.txt
```

Do remember to run tar -xvf on the 2 tgz files to extract the image files.

Answer (score 0):

I met this exception too. I find it may because you have run this python program, but when it running and download the data, you break it, and the dir have been made.

I solved this by delete the maden dir.Its `route:~/scikit_learn_data/lfw_home.`

Delete the dir lfw_funneled and lfw-funneled.tgz, and then run you program again, and the data will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: [image: Click on Factory Reset Runtime]

1. Click on factory reset runtime
2. Run all Cells

Then the error will be solved.

Reason:
Due to the low connectivity of your internet, the runtime doesn't work correctly. That's why you have to factory reset the runtime and execute all cells.
It worked for me, and the error was gone, and then the dataset got downloaded.

[image: Importing]